# Find sum and average of multiple numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to find the sum of multiple amounts and the average of the amounts given. It doesn't seem to be working but I don't know if the issue is within my compiler of if it is my code. This is what i have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    sum=0.0, average;

    cout << "Enter the numbers of data: ";
    cin >> n;

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number: ";
        cin >> num[i];
        sum += num[i];
    }

    average = sum / n;
    cout << "Average = " << average;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Offhand, I'd say you're missing the type of `sum` and `average`. What error are you getting?

Comment: where did you define `num[i]`, and why do you need an array?

Comment: Rule of thumb: it's **almost never** the compiler.  Could we see an example of inputs and resulting incorrect output and/or error messages?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't declare "num" array anywhere, also your data declarations are missing types for sum and average. They should be floats. BTW float literals need f on the end:

```
float num = 0.0f; // hold the current number
float sum = 0.0f; // store the sum so far
float average = 0.0f; // store the average at the end
```

When reading store cin straight into num, with no [i] subscript:

```
cin >> num;
sum += num;
```

This will fix the main errors. Again, read the error messages carefully, they will always tell you the line number and a message about the type of error, you just need to learn to decipher what the messages mean.

forget about the array for now, as that would need dynamic memory allocation, since the size is inputted by the user, and you should get basic program flow and variables worked out before delving into that.

"unknown symbol" or similar means you used a name, but you never declared what type of thing that was, so you forgot to declare a variable or didn't declare a type for it (just throwing a name out doesn't tell the compiler whether it's meant to be the name of e.g. a variable, a function, a class or whatever. The compiler isn't a mind reader).